# Retrieving my Flickr password

Tags: yahoo, flickr, passwords

A good year or so ago, I set up a Yahoo/Flickr account for myself mainly to reserve my username. I've tried logging in again and can't remember my password at all! Stupid of me, I know, but it's OK because I can use the password reset form.

However, when I get to the stage where I have to confirm my alternate email address, it displays this: **********@7**********.**.uk - I don't have an email address where the domain starts with 7! Yahoo won't let you sign up without verifying your email so I can't have entered a nonexistent one.

Has anybody else had this problem? And where should I go from here? I really want my sweet sweet vanity URL!

Comment: You could register that domain if it doesn't exist! It only would cost you $10.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an associated @yahoo.com or @yahoo.co.uk email address and can remember what it is you can go through the password reset process for the mail account, then once signed in on that email account you might get access to the Flickr account.

There's a reset wizard at https://edit.yahoo.com/forgotroot

1. Select "forgot password".
2. Enter ID and capcha.
3. Select "I can't access above email accounts"
4. Answer your secret questions.

Comment: I've tried this, but none of my details work. I'm beginning to wonder whether I put any of this data in. I know the answer to my birthday, country and postcode but it's not working at all!

Answer (score 0):

If no details work, then you should try and contact Yahoo support directly. After a bit of searching this is no easy task to locate, it's help wizard after help wizard.

The closest thing I found that may be useful is this "help form" but it requires a yahoo id to use. So you will probably need to setup an account to get help on your lost account.

Help form: http://help.yahoo.com/l/uk/yahoo/profiles/forms_index.html

Ask a general question through it and hopefully they will redirect it to a more appropriate support area. Don't supply a lot of private information initially.

Comment: I found this form: http://help.yahoo.com/l/uk/yahoo/edit/general.html which is the "Yahoo! Account Services Help Form". I've emailed them my problem, we'll see how it goes. Thanks for your help so far, I'll be back when they respond!